# Can I set a LayoutTransition with an Animation (instead of Animator)?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to make custom transitions on my layout. I'd like to use an xml defined "Animation" because it lets me use percentage values, while "Animator" seems to only take pixel values. The problem is LayoutTransition only seems to take "Animator" as parameter.

```
    LayoutTransition lt = new LayoutTransition();
    lt.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
    lt.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, /*ANIMATOR*/);
    view.setLayoutTransition(lt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an animator object defined by XML

```
AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context, R.animator.your_animation)
```

The XML uses the tag:

```
<objectAnimator />
```

This is different to the Animation and has a different set of properties.
These can be found at:
[Property Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#views)

Hope this helps.